# Vertical sliding panel module for Drupal 7

Tags: 7, blocks

Has anyone written a contrib module to place a block inside a sliding panel like this: http://spyrestudios.com/demos/sliding-panel-left/ . So i do not need to reinvent the wheel.

If not, i will write one :D

Comment: are you looking to create a feedback button? if that is the purpose then there is module http://drupal.org/project/feedback_simple

Comment: No, but nice module :) As far as i can see, this is only a button. I will need to have, as in link iprovided, button which on click opens a panel with user block in it. Thanks!